Can't set newlines into textarea with "&#13;" or <br>
I need to set a fixed string with newlines into a <textarea> in React/NextJS and none of the following is working, with either &#13; or <br>:
setTextAreaValue('a&#13;bc<br>def&#13;ghijkl');

            <textarea
                id="response"
                name="response"
                value={textAreaValue}
                rows={5} /* this was also tried, with no effect */



<br> is a HTML element, <textarea> does not parse/support HTML elements as values.
You'll need \n to act like a newline inside a <textarea>.
If you can't change the source-data, use a replaceAll to replace each <br> with some \n's



const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('abc<br>defghijkl');

    return <textarea value={value.replaceAll('<br>', '\n')} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>



